# What is the complexity of this recursive merge of two ordered Python lists?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, recursion

This is not an assignment, but it is related to my Data Structures class.

I just wrote this Python code to merge two ordered python lists. I do know that I could do something like this: list1 + list2. I still want to know the answer for my question - it seemed important to my professor that we learn how to write good recursive function. The time complexity of a well written recursive merge function, according to him, is O(n).

The function receives two ordered lists and merges them into another ordered list. I would say that it runs in O(n), but, at the same time, I feel that my function is not well written; I guess I can't evaluate this more precisely because I don't quite know everything that happens behind the scenes to the Python's built-in functions I use.

```
def mergeR(l1, l2):
    lfinal = []

    if not l1:
        return l2
    if not l2:
        return l1

    if l1[0] < l2[0]:
        lfinal.append(l1.pop(0))
    elif l1[0] == l2[0]:
        l2.pop(0)
    else:
        lfinal.append(l2.pop(0))

    lfinal.extend(mergeR(l1, l2))

    return lfinal
```

Comment: The answer depends on the inner workings of `python`, so in principle we can't really tell. But you can try to do experiments and see whether the running time seems linear or not.

Comment: I removed your test cases, since they don't seem to be relevant to the question you're asking.

Comment: The answer to the question as written does indeed depend on the python internals. One way to proceed would be to just point-blank assume that the python routines youse run in constant time. An alternative would be to use an [oracle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine), which amounts to saying, "I've no idea how long those python routines take but I'll keep track of how many steps my own code makes and how many times I call the python routines."